# Writing multiple lines with variables to a file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to output text to a configuration file using variables, in a single elevated line to be included in a shell script.

So far I have the code below, that creates the file with the necessary line spacing etc, but I can't figure out how to get the variables to be pulled through.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo  /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/InfluxDB.yaml << EOL
 apiVersion: 1
 datasources:
  - name: $dbname
    type: influxdb
    url: http://localhost:8086
    user: $usrname
    password: $pssword
    database: $dbname
    access: proxy
    editable: true
    isDefault: true
EOL'
```

I have also tried this, with various combinations of ", ' or '' but can't seem to get it right. I either get nothing or the variables written as text as you see them above.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "apiVersion: 1\n datasources:\n  - name: $dbname\n    type: influxdb\n    url: http://localhost:8086\n    user: $usrname\n    password: $pssword\n    database: $dbname\n    access: proxy\n    editable: true\n    isDefault: true" > /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/InfluxDB.yaml'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Welcome! Please create a minimal, reproducible example. One doesn't need all that line with all its variables to picture the problem. Supplying the variables is useful for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one of correct way is:

```
sudo sh -c "cat >> /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/InfluxDB.yaml << 'EOL'
 apiVersion: 1
 datasources:
  - name: $dbname
    type: influxdb
    url: http://localhost:8086
    user: $usrname
    password: $pssword
    database: $dbname
    access: proxy
    editable: true
    isDefault: true
EOL"
```

If you want to overwrite the file you should use ">" after cat command instead ">>".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can try this:

```
dbname=db
usrname=user
pssword=pass

sudo cat << EOL >> /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/InfluxDB.yaml
 apiVersion: 1
 datasources:
  - name: $dbname
    type: influxdb
    url: http://localhost:8086
    user: $usrname
    password: $pssword
    database: $dbname
    access: proxy
    editable: true
    isDefault: true
EOL
```

---

Output:

```
cat /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/InfluxDB.yaml

 apiVersion: 1
 datasources:
  - name: db
    type: influxdb
    url: http://localhost:8086
    user: user
    password: pass
    database: db
    access: proxy
    editable: true
    isDefault: true
```

Comment: `sudo echo "$foo" >> /etc/...` is going to execute `echo` with elevated privileges, but the redirection will still have the privileges of the invoking shell

Comment: @steeldriver Right! Deleted then... I guess there's not the same problem with the first suggestion.

Comment: same issue with `sudo cat >>` ... you could use `sudo tee -a /etc/... << EOL` instead I think?

Comment: That prints the output... `sudo tee -a /etc/... > /dev/null << EOL`?